# How to place a div and a canvas together

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to put a canvas and a div side by side?
Because I want to use the canvas to draw some stuff, and the div to display some information.

The code I tested on jsfiddle is below, but for some reason, when I do this in my code, the div just disappears.

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<div style="height: 100%;width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <th >Text1</th>
        <th >Text2</th>
      </tr>         
</div>
```

Comment: Share some code on what you've tried?

Comment: @fortunee Well, in jsfiddle i just created a canvas, with border, width and height, and after i place a div with also width and height, but for some reason, in my code when i put the canvas the div just disappers.

Comment: Ok, I just posted a solution based on your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a solution to display canvas and div side by side using float property in CSS. Check the code below

In HTML file:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"  style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<div id="div">
  
      <tr>
        <th >Text1</th>
        <th >Text2</th>
      </tr> 
 
</div>
```

Your CSS file:

```
#myCanvas{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

    #div{
      width: 49%;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      float: right;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;
     
    }
```

You can also wrap your canvas and div in external div and give CSS property of display: flex, to it and it will work too. Remember I have used flexbox to just center your table, it fine too without centered. I have used the following canvas script

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

you can see a live preview on my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Aqib_2000/pen/VwPRZdM)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap in one `div` and apply style to that wrapper `display: flex` . See the snippet

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">   </canvas>
  <div style="height: 100%;width: 100%;margin-left: 20px">
      <tr>
        <th >Text1</th>
        <th >Text2</th>
      </tr>         
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an example of them side by side. There’s other ways to place them also.

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="stuff"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#canvas {
  border: solid 2px red;
}

#stuff {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

JS

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
```

https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/abpMoLN

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap the `canvas` and the `div` in a parent `div` with a class of `wrapper` and set a display of flex, this should place both elements side by side.

You can read about [CSS Flexbox here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  <div style="height: 100%;width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <th >Text1</th>
        <th >Text2</th>
      </tr>         
  </div>
</div>
```